# WordPress + Woo - Doesn't save product descriptions

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Comrades, good morning, I need your help, this is the first time I have such a problem.
In general, we have WP + Woo plus a couple of fields for goods via ACF (composition, etc.)
Products were imported from CSV and started to fill in descriptions.
But when you click on the "update" button, the entered information is not saved + a redirect to the "Posts" page occurs.

The only thing I noticed is that there is such an error when the text is large, at least 3-4 lines. If less, then everything works out.

Comment: What is the error you are facing?

Comment: wp does not show me any error messages, just redirect me to "post" page and doesn't save my changes